# Removing Internet Explorer 7

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

Recently installed Internet Explorer 7 on an Windows XP SP3 box (was Internet Explorer 6 prior).

Internet Explorer 7 promised on install that it "can be uninstalled" via the Add/Remove Programs applet.

It installed successfully, and the machine was rebooted. After running it for a few minutes, it was uninstalled via Add/Remove Programs, which also completed successfully. The machine was then rebooted again.

However, Internet Explorer is still at version 7. Internet Explorer 6 was not restored. `%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe` still reports version 7 on the executable details, and when launched it is clearly version 7 (both in appearance and reported by the About box).

Is there a way to fully remove it? (that is, rollback to Internet Explorer 6?) Answers to the effect of "why would you want to?" are not constructive :)

I already attempted the instructions in *[How to uninstall Internet Explorer 7 (KB 927177)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927177)* with no success. Their alternative method didn't work as `%windir%\ie7` has already been removed, which presumably contained the uninstallation files.

**EDIT: I am fully aware of security issues with Internet Explorer 6. I am also aware that many people cannot conceive of any reason to ever revert to it. *None of this is constructive or in any way related to the question put forth.***

Comment: I'm somewhat curious why would one install the four-year-old IE 7, and even more curious why [go back to IE 6 willingly](https://twitter.com/Microsoft/status/43753653189885952).

Comment: I do strongly feel that we need repeat the typical warning that IE6 is extremely outdated. It will render many modern pages incorrectly, it lacks the security features of more modern browsers, and it is rapidly approaching the end of its security support life cycle. In short, all use of IE6 should be eliminated as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Windows XP's System Restore](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306084) to back up to a point in time before you installed Internet Explorer 7.

Comment: If you don't have System Restore on, or a backup, and you've axed the uninstall files, you may be SOL short of trying to copy files from another XP machine that still has IE6, but even that will be tricky at best due to registry changes that may or may not have taken place during you IE7 install and uninstall(s).